# Microstack-My VMs cannot access the Internet

Tags: networking, openstack, virtualization, microstack

So I have installes Microstack in an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS PC.
Well i can ssh to my VM from the host(where miccostack is installed), but my VM cannot access the Internet.

I have created an instance named osm and i have associated a floating ip to it.

```
(openstack) server list
+--------------------------------------+------+--------+-----------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| ID                                   | Name | Status | Networks                          | Image      | Flavor    |
+--------------------------------------+------+--------+-----------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| e12dc245-da35-424a-a9b2-06067e2f5555 | osm  | ACTIVE | test=192.168.222.246, 10.20.20.30 | ubuntu1804 | m1.medium |
+--------------------------------------+------+--------+-----------------------------------+------------+-----------+
```

This is my network list

```
 (openstack) network list
+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| ID                                   | Name     | Subnets                              |
+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| c4968a12-662f-4ca6-8392-a6dc3f81e3ba | external | bcd86099-e801-477b-bf0c-978ec84bb708 |
| f83255dd-42d1-4fed-ad21-e9d1ec887fa8 | test     | a7064161-4d11-4ca7-be55-47e5a6d92724 |
+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
```

Each network has its own subnet with these details:
external-subnet

```
(openstack) subnet show external-subnet
+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field             | Value                                                                                                                                                                             |
+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| allocation_pools  | 10.20.20.1-10.20.20.82                                                                                                                                                            |
| cidr              | 10.20.20.0/24                                                                                                                                                                     |
| created_at        | 2020-07-06T08:06:26Z                                                                                                                                                              |
| description       |                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| dns_nameservers   | 8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8                                                                                                                                                                  |
| enable_dhcp       | False                                                                                                                                                                             |
| gateway_ip        | 10.20.20.83                                                                                                                                                                       |
| host_routes       |                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| id                | bcd86099-e801-477b-bf0c-978ec84bb708                                                                                                                                              |
| ip_version        | 4                                                                                                                                                                                 |
| ipv6_address_mode | None                                                                                                                                                                              |
| ipv6_ra_mode      | None                                                                                                                                                                              |
| location          | Munch({'cloud': '', 'region_name': '', 'zone': None, 'project': Munch({'id': '54ba9ffa36ca424fac395b6c774fd2a3', 'name': 'admin', 'domain_id': None, 'domain_name': 'default'})}) |
| name              | external-subnet                                                                                                                                                                   |
| network_id        | c4968a12-662f-4ca6-8392-a6dc3f81e3ba                                                                                                                                              |
| prefix_length     | None                                                                                                                                                                              |
| project_id        | 54ba9ffa36ca424fac395b6c774fd2a3                                                                                                                                                  |
| revision_number   | 22                                                                                                                                                                                |
| segment_id        | None                                                                                                                                                                              |
| service_types     |                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| subnetpool_id     | None                                                                                                                                                                              |
| tags              |                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| updated_at        | 2020-10-12T10:49:35Z                                                                                                                                                              |
+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

test-subnet

```
(openstack) subnet show test-subnet
+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field             | Value                                                                                                                                                                             |
+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| allocation_pools  | 192.168.222.2-192.168.222.254                                                                                                                                                     |
| cidr              | 192.168.222.0/24                                                                                                                                                                  |
| created_at        | 2020-07-06T08:06:20Z                                                                                                                                                              |
| description       |                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| dns_nameservers   | 8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8                                                                                                                                                                  |
| enable_dhcp       | True                                                                                                                                                                              |
| gateway_ip        | 192.168.222.1                                                                                                                                                                     |
| host_routes       |                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| id                | a7064161-4d11-4ca7-be55-47e5a6d92724                                                                                                                                              |
| ip_version        | 4                                                                                                                                                                                 |
| ipv6_address_mode | None                                                                                                                                                                              |
| ipv6_ra_mode      | None                                                                                                                                                                              |
| location          | Munch({'cloud': '', 'region_name': '', 'zone': None, 'project': Munch({'id': '54ba9ffa36ca424fac395b6c774fd2a3', 'name': 'admin', 'domain_id': None, 'domain_name': 'default'})}) |
| name              | test-subnet                                                                                                                                                                       |
| network_id        | f83255dd-42d1-4fed-ad21-e9d1ec887fa8                                                                                                                                              |
| prefix_length     | None                                                                                                                                                                              |
| project_id        | 54ba9ffa36ca424fac395b6c774fd2a3                                                                                                                                                  |
| revision_number   | 7                                                                                                                                                                                 |
| segment_id        | None                                                                                                                                                                              |
| service_types     |                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| subnetpool_id     | None                                                                                                                                                                              |
| tags              |                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| updated_at        | 2020-10-12T10:49:52Z                                                                                                                                                                |
+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

These are the information about the router which is connected to the external and test network

```
(openstack) router list
+--------------------------------------+-------------+--------+-------+----------------------------------+-------------+-------+
| ID                                   | Name        | Status | State | Project                          | Distributed | HA    |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+--------+-------+----------------------------------+-------------+-------+
| b935bc17-d379-4aa8-b040-5a770741de23 | test-router | ACTIVE | UP    | 54ba9ffa36ca424fac395b6c774fd2a3 | False       | False |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+--------+-------+----------------------------------+-------------+-------+
(openstack) router show test-router
+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field                   | Value                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| admin_state_up          | UP                                                                                                                                                                                      |
| availability_zone_hints |                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| availability_zones      | nova                                                                                                                                                                                    |
| created_at              | 2020-07-06T08:06:28Z                                                                                                                                                                    |
| description             |                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| distributed             | False                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| external_gateway_info   | {"network_id": "c4968a12-662f-4ca6-8392-a6dc3f81e3ba", "external_fixed_ips": [{"subnet_id": "bcd86099-e801-477b-bf0c-978ec84bb708", "ip_address": "10.20.20.83"}], "enable_snat": true} |
| flavor_id               | None                                                                                                                                                                                    |
| ha                      | False                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| id                      | b935bc17-d379-4aa8-b040-5a770741de23                                                                                                                                                    |
| interfaces_info         | [{"port_id": "6f935a4f-e1b0-41bf-aefb-dd6f9b929f69", "ip_address": "192.168.222.1", "subnet_id": "a7064161-4d11-4ca7-be55-47e5a6d92724"}]                                               |
| location                | Munch({'cloud': '', 'region_name': '', 'zone': None, 'project': Munch({'id': '54ba9ffa36ca424fac395b6c774fd2a3', 'name': 'admin', 'domain_id': None, 'domain_name': 'default'})})       |
| name                    | test-router                                                                                                                                                                             |
| project_id              | 54ba9ffa36ca424fac395b6c774fd2a3                                                                                                                                                        |
| revision_number         | 23                                                                                                                                                                                      |
| routes                  |                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| status                  | ACTIVE                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| tags                    |                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| updated_at              | 2020-10-11T14:52:29Z                                                                                                                                                                    |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My VM can ping 192.168.222.1(gateway),10.20.20.83(gateway),10.20.20.1(host-microstack) but cannot access the internet. For example i cannot ping 8.8.8.8

```
ubuntu@osm:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.20.20.30 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.20.20.30 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.20.20.30 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.20.20.30 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4055ms
pipe 3
```

I assume that maybe the problem is related to the fact that the status of the port at 10.20.20.30 is N/A, but I am not sure

```
(openstack) port list
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| ID                                   | Name | MAC Address       | Fixed IP Addresses                                                             | Status |
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| 029f8880-9e7c-4b9e-a8e8-b27496ec542e |      | fa:16:3e:2e:ac:b5 | ip_address='10.20.20.30', subnet_id='bcd86099-e801-477b-bf0c-978ec84bb708'     | N/A    |
| 6f935a4f-e1b0-41bf-aefb-dd6f9b929f69 |      | fa:16:3e:0d:65:36 | ip_address='192.168.222.1', subnet_id='a7064161-4d11-4ca7-be55-47e5a6d92724'   | ACTIVE |
| 9c46a483-ee64-4d0a-8eb4-aa2b5cc083b7 |      | fa:16:3e:66:da:8a | ip_address='10.20.20.83', subnet_id='bcd86099-e801-477b-bf0c-978ec84bb708'     | ACTIVE |
| c2444040-b8d5-4009-8019-10779ecb7d92 |      | fa:16:3e:4e:93:c8 | ip_address='192.168.222.246', subnet_id='a7064161-4d11-4ca7-be55-47e5a6d92724' | ACTIVE |
| cc79a6f2-a4c1-47de-b27b-9a2018dab595 |      | fa:16:3e:e4:17:32 | ip_address='192.168.222.2', subnet_id='a7064161-4d11-4ca7-be55-47e5a6d92724'   | ACTIVE |
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

While I was searching for this issue I found that executing these commands to the host machine(where Microstack is installed) may fix the problem

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.20.20.1/24 ! -d 10.20.20.1/24 -j MASQUERADE

sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

But unfortunatelly nothing happened and I still have this issue.
Any piece of advice would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

So, I never figured out what was the real problem there. But I made some changes and it finally worked for me.
So:

1.I uninstalled the microstack I had on my PC.

```
sudo snap remove microstack --purge
```

2.I installed the latest microstack I found on [microstack.run](https://microstack.run) site. In my case I used
beta and devmode flags, but I recommend you to visit [microstack.run](https://microstack.run) to check what is
the most recommended microstack

```
   sudo snap install microstack --beta --devmode

   sudo microstack init --auto --control
```

3.I kept the network configuration the same as it was, when microstack was installed. I made these changes:

```
   (openstack) subnet set --dhcp external-subnet
   (openstack) subnet set --dhcp test-subnet
   (openstack) subnet set --dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 external-subnet
   (openstack) subnet set --dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 test-subnet
   (openstack) network set --share external
   (openstack) network set --share test
```

4.I ran these commands I found at [bugs.launchpad.net/microstack/+bug/1812415](https://bugs.launchpad.net/microstack/+bug/1812415) on the host machine:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.20.20.1/24 ! -d 10.20.20.1/24 -j MASQUERADE

sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

5.I created the image and launch a new instance. And finally I managed to ping 8.8.8.8 and have access on the Internet.

```
ubuntu@osm:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=29.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=28.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=114 time=28.6 ms
```

At  this point I want to mention that I kept the security group rules the way it was.

I hope all these be helpful to someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

### Case

I encountered a server power failure, resulting ping floating ip, sometime timeout and sometime ok.

when I execute "openstack port list" check the port detail, port status is `N/A`. In Dashboard the port status is `creating`

### Solution

renew an ip from DHCP, and re-bind floating ip with the vm. That will keep the floating ip.

**Operation steps**

1. Separate the interface and select the internal interface of the virtual machine.
2. Connect the interface and select the network.
3. Floating IP associated virtual machine.

Answer (score -1):

I started having this issue as well. I tried the solution suggested above of adding a POSTROUTING rule. This worked for me for a short while. After reboot I faced the same error and applying the POSTROUTING rule didn't resolve it.

Checking the iptable rules with `sudo iptables -L -v -n --line-numbers` and `sudo iptables -L -v -n -t nat --line-numbers` showed that the packets were being consumed by iptable rules set by docker. To resolve this, in addition to `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.20.20.1/24 ! -d 10.20.20.1/24 -j MASQUERADE` I also inserted FORWARD rules for the microstack IP range like below.

```bash
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.20.20.1/24 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -I FORWARD -d 10.20.20.1/24 -j ACCEPT
```

After that I got the traffic flowing. I hope this helps someone else.